# Rotating the object makes it smaller

Tags: java, math, opengl-es, rotation

when I rotate a model matrix in opengl es with the function I created, the model matrix makes the model smaller while rotating, and I don't understand why.

Here is the code of the rotating function(Rotating around the z axis only).

```
public void rotateZ(float angle){
    float cos = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
    float sin = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));
    Matrix4x4 ret = IdentityM();
    ret.setValue(cos, 0, 0);
    ret.setValue(-sin, 0, 1);

    ret.setValue(sin, 1, 0);
    ret.setValue(cos, 1, 1);

    Multiply(ret);
}
```

And here is the code of the multiplication function:

```
public void Multiply(Matrix4x4 m){
        float[][] m1 = m.toFloatMat();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                float value = 0f;
                for(int t = 0; t < 4; t++){
                    value += matrix[i][t] * m1[t][j];
                }
                matrix[i][j] = value;
            }
        }
}
```

And the setValue function:

```
public void setValue(float v, int i, int j){
        matrix[i][j] = v;
}
```

The object is only getting smaller and I don't understand why ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Multiply` function, you are overwriting the original matrix while calculating the product. Make a temporary matrix to store the result, and then write it back to the class member `matrix`.

Comment: Upps it's the second time I get these little mistakes, it's driving me crazy lol